# Saving date field programmatically on node, but not on profile

Tags: datetime, users, entities

I'm saving some date field on the code both on node and profile entity. I'm success on saving it for nodes, but when I try to save for profile2 entity, using the same chunck of code, no data is saved.

I'm doing this to nodes (after creating a new node with entity API):

```
// Creating a node and an entity wrapper
$entity = entity_create('node', $values);
$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
// Saving the date field
$entity->field_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
   'value' => strtotime($date),
   'timezone' => date_default_timezone(),
   'timezone_db' => date_default_timezone(),
   'date_type' => 'datestamp'
 );
//Saving the node 
$ewrapper->save();
```

And almost the same way with profiles:

```
//Creating a profile2 'info' bundle     
$profile_info = profile2_create(array('type' => 'info', 'uid' => $user->uid));
// Trying to save the date field, same way as above
$profile_info->field_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
   'value' => strtotime($mydate),
   'timezone' => date_default_timezone(),
   'timezone_db' => date_default_timezone(),
   'date_type' => 'datestamp'
 );
// Saving the profile
profile2_save($profile_info);
```

If someone knows what is happening I'd appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

This might or might not fix your problem but since you're using entity metadata wrappers, you should use them fully:

```
$profile = profile2_create(...);
$profile_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile);
$profile_wrapper->field_date = array(...);
$profile_wrapper->save();
```

The above snippet can also be used with nodes, just replacing the creation & wrapper instantiation.

Also, if you're using a single timezone, you can safely omit it and just specify the actual timestamp value.  You should probably omit the 'date_type' key too, that's inferred by the field config and could be causing issues.

**In fact, you should just do:** `$profile_wrapper->field_date = 123456; // (timestamp)`

Tested locally and it works!

You shouldn't use LANGUAGE_NONE or [0] indices because not only might it break i18n if you're translating fields but it's also not very robust.